# How to add razor isolated/code behind CSS classes in MudBlazor components?

Tags: css, blazor, mudblazor

in my codebehind file I have defined a css class. This is pulled when I use the "class" attribute on normal HTML elements (in the example: ). However, if the class sits on a MudElement ("Class"), the change is not pulled. The class name is set, but the style is not applied.

What's the problem?

MainLayout.razor:

```
<MudContainer Class="redBorder">
    <span class="redBorder">
        @Body
    </span>
</MudContainer>
```

MainLayout.razor.css:

```
.redBorder {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: can you try adding !important to style to see if it is priority issue?

Comment: I tried, but thats not the problem. I event cant see the style (and also not overriden) in F12 - for the one element

Comment: inspect this div in dev tools and see if it has style, then add the stying in dev tools? also share screenshot

Comment: Have you tried `::deep` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#child-component-support

Comment: The reason what it doesn't work is because the `Class` attribute in the MudBlazor component is actually a Parameter [note the capital C] and used by the component to internally build it's Css.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes exactly and the goal was to put custom CSS classes inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't work with razor isolated css, the razor isolated/code behind css adds an id to each class when compiled and linking doesn't seem to work.

You can create a separate css file and save it in your wwwroot/css folder (don't forget to add a link to that file in your index.html file.) Then the classes there can be applied on top of the MudBlazor components Class property.

Comment: Thanks you are right this works. But I am looking forward if there is workaround to achieve it

Comment: The weird thing is: It seems to work when im in debugging mode. When i start without debugging the styles are not pulled.

Comment: @sampa have you tried clearing your cache.

Comment: Yes, also with inkognito mode, deleting, debug folde rand more

Comment: @sampa that's strange, you might want to check browser console to see that the css file is being loaded. And also play around with the link to the css file in index.html. With and without '/' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Might have misinterpreted your question. If not, it should be possbile like this:

```
  <div>
    <MudContainer Class="redBorder">
        <span class="redBorder">
            @Body
        </span>
    </MudContainer>
    </div>

::deep .redBorder {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If you want to have a CSS code behind file, you need to use ::deep for the HTML to understand. Only counts for code behind.

Otherwise, you can check out your _Host.cshtml or index.cshtml (depend on project). The order of CSS files is important here.