# What does the Class Tag mean on MudBlazor Components?

Tags: razor, mudblazor

I created a new MudBlazor project using the dotnet template they describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com). I opened up the project and noticed the class tag on the MudContainer property `<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="my-16 pt-16">` I was confused on what this was, and I couldn't find anything in my solution with the name "my-16" or "pt-16".

Here's a more extended code:

**MainLayout.Razor**

```html
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudThemeProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
   ... (Extra code taken out)

    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="my-16 pt-16">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

When I searched the API documentation [here](https://mudblazor.com/api/container#properties), and any other component that has this tag, all I found was this description: "*User class names, separated by space.*" which I got no help from. I then added in a file called `MainLayout.razor.css` with this test class:

```css
.test {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

and tried to put test into the class tag, but it had no effect. Overall I'm at a totall loss on two things:

1. What does the class tag mean?
2. Where can I find the `my-16` and `pt-16` classes provided?

Comment: It's the CSS class used by the component, and combined with any internal css in the component.  `my-16 pt-16` can be found as css definitions in the MudBlazor css file.  `my-16` for instance is a margin in the y direction of 16 points [I believe].

Comment: Oh and btw the reason your `.test` class didn't get applied was due to **razor isolated css** problems, this is [my solution for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76360083/11779494), however there are other workarounds aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the class tag mean?

There is `class` (lowercase), which is an HTML class attribute and there is `Class` (capital C), which is a MudBlazor property.

MudBlazor components expose the `Class` property which get added on top of the components underlying HTML elements `class` attribute.

The code below is a snippet of `MudContainer` component.

```
<div @attributes="UserAttributes" class="@Classname" style="@Style">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    string Classname =>
        new CssBuilder("mud-container")
            .AddClass($"mud-container-fixed", Fixed)
            .AddClass($"mud-container-maxwidth-{MaxWidth.ToDescriptionString()}", !Fixed)
            .AddClass(Class) 
            .Build();
}
```

`.AddClass(Class)` <- this is where the classes you define in the Class property get added.

So similar to how you add classes to an HTML element, you use MudBlazor components `Class` property to add your classes. i.e. by seperating them with spaces.

```
<div class="bio-text bio-heading">My Bio</div>

<MudText Class="bio-text bio-heading">My Bio</MudText>
```

> Where can I find the my-16 and pt-16 classes provided?

`my-16` and `pt-16` are CSS utility classes, these two are specifically used for [spacing](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/spacing#size).

You should have a read through [what are CSS utility classes](https://blog.logrocket.com/css-utility-classes-library-extendable-styles/). In a few words, they're also classes that you can use.